# If no Cauchy subsequence exists, must a uniformly separated subsequence exist?

Tags: convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

Given a sequence $(x_n)$ in a metric space $M$, call it *uniformly separated* if all pairwise distances $d(x_n,x_m)$ between distinct terms are uniformly bounded away from zero.

Suppose that a given sequence $(x_n)$  has the property that it has no Cauchy subsequence. Must it have a uniformly separated subsequence?

A couple of my students asserted this in homework without watertight proof, and proof or disproof is eluding me. Clearly any counterexample cannot be in ${\mathbb R}^n$. Enjoy!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A proof can be inferred from the answers to an earlier question.

[Which metric spaces are totally bounded?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7210/which-metric-spaces-are-totally-bounded/)

Comment: Indeed, thanks! And distinctly cute, since rearrangements apparently are involved.